# GRUB2 not showing windows 10 after Ubuntu 19.10 install as third OS on my pc, among Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

I had a perfectly working dual-boot, but last week I plugged in an SSD of 250GB to install Ubuntu 19.10 on (Among existing Windows 10 (128GB SSD) and Ubuntu 18.04 (800GB-ish) installation). Unfortunately, it did not turn out to be as easy as expected. The problem is as follows.

Whenever I boot my system, I only get to choose between Ubuntu 18.04 and my new Ubuntu 19.10 but no windows is found by the GRUB2 bootloader. To solve the problem I ran the boot-repair tool on my new system which gave me the following information dump:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8r4rpB5SVv/

Focussing on the repair suggested by boot-repair I would have to create a >1MB, unformatted filesystem with bios_grub flag. However, this gives me two problems as well. Assuming it is desired that I created this partition on my new drive, I am unable to adjust the partitions on this active OS (obviously... I suppose). The second problem is that I am unable to flag an unformatted filesystem, the program does not allow me to manage these flags.

If any information is missing, please let me know and I will update my post.

I hope someone is able to help me with this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: When you choose Ubuntu 18.04 to boot, doesn't Ubuntu 18.04's grub menu appear with your Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 entries? Use liveCD, that is Ubuntu installation disk by selecting Try Ubuntu without installing. Open there Gparted and try.

Comment: It used to do so indeed! However, that got messed up when I ran boot-repair on ubuntu 19.10... as i was trying to get it all in the same bootloader.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as useless, but you could post your own explaining how you solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the boot repair does work on the Ubuntu 18.04 system. After which I performed a `sudo update-grub` to get my windows system & ubuntu 19.10 system in the bootloader of the /dev/sdc5 drive.

I don't understand why this is works. So, if someone can clarify this it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: When you have boot/partition table problems, you usually need to boot your system from a live CD/USB drive so that your main drive is unmounted and can be safely modified. Whenever I need to work on grub, I use grub-customizer. It allows you to examine and change the menu using a user friendly GUI interface. It can also write the boot loader to the main disk so your new menu is the one that is used. Like gparted, it lets you setup a number of changes and only applies them when you tell it to.